# Do I have to manually check for updates?

Tags: ps-vita

I noticed there's a manual button to check for updates on the Live Area for games. If a game update is out will launching the game check for updates or do I have to manually check for updates? Do PSP games on the Vita auto/not-auto update just like PS Vita games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your Vita will not automatically check for updates.

On the other hand, several common tasks, such as trying to download a game from the PSNetwork Store, will check for updates, and notify you that a new update is available.

Comment: Wait, trying to download an *unrelated* game will check for updates from *all* games? Say a PSP game and a Vita game had an update and I download a brand new Vita game, will the notification tell me of both updates, neither...?

Comment: I have noticed the orange arrow at the games slash screen without ever manually clicking the update icon so i think that this is correct.